# How to use ROW_NUMBER() function mysql after the ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, window-functions

```
SELECT user.id
      ,user.emp_id
      ,user.name,COUNT(transfer.record_name) AS current_rank
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS count
FROM transfer AS transfer
LEFT JOIN users AS user ON user.emp_id= transfer.user_id
WHERE transfer.lobs= 0
AND transfer.shift_date = '2020-03-27'
GROUP BY user.emp_id
ORDER BY current_rank DESC
```

This query will give me a result of like this:

```
user.id|   user.emp_id|   user.name|   current_rank|   count
25           1234          test1           4             4
30           4321          test2           2             2
18           5678          test3           1             1
12           8765          test4           1             3
```

My goal is to use ORDER BY DESC first so that I can order the `current_rank` and the `count` column should have the count of:

```
user.id|   user.emp_id|   user.name|   current_rank|   count
25           1234          test1           4             1
30           4321          test2           2             2
18           5678          test3           1             3
12           8765          test4           1             4
```

How can I use the ROW_NUMBER() function after I ORDER BY my `current_rank` column?

Thank you any help. I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `ROW_NUMBER()` is not affected by the sort in the query.

Instead, it accepts an `ORDER BY` option within its `OVER` clause: without it, the ordering of `ROW_NUMBER()` is *undefined*, meaning that the database is free to order the rows as it likes. You may observe that the same ordering is used over consecutive executions, but the database does not guarantee it.

So, do add an `ORDER BY` to the window function:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(transfer.record_name) DESC) AS count
```